# Passing JSON to Django template and Grunt

Tags: json, django, gruntjs

My setup consists of a lot of .js files being used in my `base.html` template and the same list being repeated in my `Gruntfile.js` when concatenating all the files for production.

How can I have the list of files in a single JSON (or whatever other format) and be able to pass it to both Django and Grunt?

Here's a simplified example:

`base.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <script src="static/some.js"></script>
    <!-- a lot more js files go here -->
</body>
</html>
```

`Gruntfile.js`:

```
uglify: {
  options:{},
  build: {
    options:{
      report: 'min'
    },
    files: {
      'static/some.min.js': [
        'static/some.js',
        // lots of other js files go here
      ]
    }
}
```

I know that Grunt can load JSON files through `grunt.file.readJSON('files.json')` or `require('files.json')` but how can I do the same in Django templates?

Comment: Is it possible to concatenate/combine all your JavaScript files in your Grunt task? Then you can just have one `<script>` tag in your HTML/Django template.

Comment: It is a single js file when it goes into production, but in development there are 100-ish separate js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is interested, here's what I went for:

sample.json:

```
{
  "files": [
    "file1.js",
    "file2.js"
  ]
}
```

Grunt task:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var generalJS = prepare(grunt.file.readJSON('sample.json'));

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
        options:{},
      build: {
        options:{},
        files: {
          'sample.min.js': generalJS.files
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify']);
}
```

Django template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def render_js_files(file_location):

    result = ""
    static_base_path = settings.STATIC_DIR
    json_js_files_path = os.path.join(static_base_path, file_location)
    json_data = open(json_js_files_path)
    data = json.load(json_data)
    files_dirs = data['files']
    json_data.close()
    src_template = "<script src='%s'></script>\n"
    for js_file_path in files_dirs:
        result += src_template % urljoin(PrefixNode.handle_simple("STATIC_URL"), js_file_path)
    return result
```

Usage in base.html:

```
{% render_js_files 'sample.json' %}
```